# Load directives dynamically using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am wrapping the HTML "select" element with my own directive. This directive should create a Dropdown menu representing it's options.

I tag the select element with my custom "arBootstrapSelect" directive/attribute.
This directive appends a Dropdown menu with the options inside it repeated by ng-repeat.

The "option" elements in the "select" element are tagged with "arBootstrapSelectOption". They should have a "content" attribute, representing a dynamic directive. This dynamic directive should be compiled and shown in the Dropdown menu.

Basiclly, each option(tagged by "arBootstrapSelectOption") compiles it's "content" attribute using the $compile service and injects it into a list living in the arBootstrapSelect directive. After that arBootstrapSelect should show the compiled options using ng-repeat. Hope it's not too complicated.
I am getting [Error Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/interr?p0=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7Boption%5B1%5D%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24parse%3Aisecdom%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.2%2F%24parse%2Fisecdom%3Fp0%3Doption%255B1%255D)

HTML:

```
<select ar-bootstrap-select class="form-control">
                <option ar-bootstrap-select-option value={{$index}} ng-repeat="c in countries" content="<ar-country country-id='{{$index}}'></ar-country>">


                </option>
            </select>


<div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Dropdown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li ng-repeat="option in arBootstrapSelectOptions">
                        {{option[1]}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

My directives:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('mainApp');

app.directive('arBootstrapSelect', function ($interval, $compile) {
    $scope.arBootstrapSelectOptions = [];

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        //element.hide();

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
        scope: true
    }

});

app.directive('arBootstrapSelectOption', function ($compile) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.arBootstrapSelectOptions.push([attrs.value, $compile(attrs.content)(scope)]);
    }

    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
    }

});
})();
```

This works, but it's ugly and slow:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('mainApp');

app.directive('arBootstrapSelect', function ($interval, $compile) {
    //$scope.arBootstrapSelectOptions = [];

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        //element.hide();

        scope.$on('arBootstrapSelectNewItem', function (event, data) {
            var test = $('<li></li>').append(data);
            element.parent().find('.dropdown-menu').append(test);

        });

    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link,
        scope: true,
        transclude: true
    }

});

app.directive('arBootstrapSelectOption', function ($compile) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        //scope.arBootstrapSelectOptions.push([attrs.value, $compile(attrs.content)(scope)]);
        scope.$emit('arBootstrapSelectNewItem', $compile(attrs.content)(scope));

    }

    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    }

});
})();
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace/augment `<select>` with a custom select? For the purposes of this question is `<select>` important? And if not, can you reduce the example? I suggest removing anything and everything (styling, controls, markup) that is not relevant. Give an example of what you want the final result to look like. Also, the error seems to be related to interpolation - are you certain it is in the code you posted (e.g. not in `arCountry` directive, for example)?

Comment: Bottom line, I'm compiling a directive and storing it in it's compiled state in a list. How do I load it using ng-repeat?

Comment: Again, too broad. I can try to give you *a* solution, but without understanding your precise issue, it may be off the mark. And. to be precise, you are storing a compiled-and-linked element. Once you have the elements, you can iterate and place them in the DOM - of course, that would be unnecessarily recreating what `ng-repeat` is doing

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your specific example, so I'll answer at a conceptual level.

It seems that at a high level all you want to is to specify a user-provided template for `ng-repeat` (e.g. `<ar-country country-id='{{$index}}'>`) and place it within a directive-provided template (e.g. within `<li>`).

It would be easier and more user-friendly to provide the template as content, rather than as an attribute. Then, all you'd need is to transclude the content. (I'm avoiding here the use of `<option>` since it is a directive on its own and I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do - I'll use `<my-option>` instead):

```
<my-option ng-repeat="c in countries">
  <ar-country country-id='{{$index}}'></ar-country>
<my-option>
```

The directive would look like so:

```
.directive("myOption", function(){
  return {
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<li ng-transclude></li>'
  }
});
```

This will create conceptually the following HTML:

```
<my-option>
  <li><ar-country country-id="0"></ar-country></li>
</my-option>
<my-option>
  <li><ar-country country-id="1"></ar-country></li>
</my-option>
..
```

(The directive `arCountry` will also be compiled and linked, and may generate its own content)

Additionally, if the parent needs to register each child, it's better to use `require` to communicate rather than `$emit`/`$on`. So, the `parent` needs to define a controller with a function to register children. And, again, if you need to supply an additional template, then transclude the content:

```
<my-select>
  <my-option ng-repeat="c in countries>
    <ar-country country-id='{{$index}}'></ar-country>
  </my-option>
</my-select>
```

```
.directive("mySelect", function(){
  return {
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<h1>heading</h1><div ng-transclude></div>',
    controller: function(){
      // this can be called by the child
      this.registerChild = function(childElement, childController){
        // store the children, if needed
      }
    }
  }
});
```

To make use of `this.registerChild` we'd need to make `myOption` use [`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-):

```
.directive("myOption", function(){
  return {
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<li ng-transclude></li>'
    require: ['myOption', '^mySelect'],
    controller: function(){
      // you can define some functions here
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls){
      var me = ctrls[0], 
          selectCtrl = ctrls[1];

      selectCtrl.registerChild(element, me);
  }
});
```